# Qt5: как получить ASCII символа в QString

Tags: c++, qt5

Дана некоторая строка QString. Мне необходимо взять некоторый символ из неё получить его целочисленное ASCII представление. Как это сделать?

Comment: всё зависит от кодировки в которую вы будете переводить, если в UTF8, то там некоторые символы (например русские) имеют многобайтовый вид, но скорее всего вам подойдёт `QString::toLocal8Bit`

Comment: лучше пользуйтесь способом конвертации через QChar, QString.at(10).toLatin1()  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qchar.html#toLatin1

Comment: @PavelGridin Всё это нужно для того, чтобы провернуть сортировку.
Задача состоит в том, чтобы реализовать бинарный поиск по алфавиту Морзянка - Английский